# Is caching necessary for dataframe which is reused before the first Action?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe, which I independently transform in different ways before joining result in the final DF.
Intermediate transformed dataframes are never used in any "Actions".
The first action is ever called only after all parts are joined together.
My question is - should I cache the first dataframe then?
Example:

```
arpu_df=get_arpu_df(..). #.cache() will help here?
sample_by_arpu_ranges=arpu_df.filter("arpu>50").sample(False,0.4)\
    .union(
        arpu_df.filter("arpu>20 and arpu<=50").sample(False,0.1)
        )\
    .union(
        arpu_df.filter("arpu<=20").sample(False,0.02)
        ).select("base_subsc_id")
sample_by_arpu_ranges.count()
```

`sample` is  transformation, as far as I know.
I wonder whether the `arpu_df` part will be recomputed to apply each of the filters, or the logical plan builder will understand that it can reuse it in the different parts of the plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache will get triggered only after calling an action hence in your case the answer is **no** the `cache` will not be beneficial before calling `sample_by_arpu_ranges.count()`. A common work around is to call the less expensive action which is `count()` just after `cache()`, then your code would look as the next one:

```py
arpu_df=get_arpu_df(..)

arpu_df.cache()
arpu_df.count()

sample_by_arpu_ranges=arpu_df.filter("arpu>50").sample(False,0.4)\
    .union(
        arpu_df.filter("arpu>20 and arpu<=50").sample(False,0.1)
        )\
    .union(
        arpu_df.filter("arpu<=20").sample(False,0.02)
        ).select("base_subsc_id")
sample_by_arpu_ranges.count()
```

Comment: So, am I right that  without breaking single transformation in the way you suggested - the `get_arpu_df` computation will happen several times (even though it gets reused within the same logical plan)?

Comment: In your case arpu_df will be populated again and again when calling an action, loading the original data from its source. With cache instead of loading the data from the source disk and memory storage will be used that is the only difference between your version and the one i posted

Answer (score 0):

The answer is inside your question. You only have one action, so all your transformations will be done at that time. In that case you don't need to persist (or cache) your dataframe.

Persist is usefull only if you will need to compute again the transformations

example :

```
arpu_df=get_arpu_df(..)
sample_by_arpu_ranges=arpu_df.filter("arpu>50").sample(False,0.4)\
    .union(
        arpu_df.filter("arpu>20 and arpu<=50").sample(False,0.1)
        )\
    .union(
        arpu_df.filter("arpu<=20").sample(False,0.02)
        ).select("base_subsc_id").persist() //here you persist sample_by_arpu_ranges because you know you will have multiple actions on it

sample_by_arpu_ranges.count() // 1st action

sample_by_arpu_ranges.write.parquet("path") // 2nd action
```

In the example, sample_by_arpu_ranges will be persist during 1st action, thus for the 2nd action, sample_by_arpu_ranges will be ready.

-> Without persist with one action :

```
arpu_df = spark.read.parquet(path) 
sample_by_arpu_ranges=arpu_df.filter(...)
sample_by_arpu_ranges.count()
```

what's happening :

- sample_by_arpu_ranges.count()
- arpu_df = spark.read.parquet(path)
- sample_by_arpu_ranges=arpu_df.filter(...)
- count

--> does not keep arpu_df or sample_by_arpu_ranges but you don't need it anymore

-> Without persist with multiple actions :

```
arpu_df = spark.read.parquet(path) 
sample_by_arpu_ranges=arpu_df.filter(...)
arpu_df.count()
sample_by_arpu_ranges.count()
```

what's happening :

- arpu_df.count()
- arpu_df = spark.read.parquet(path)
- count

--> does not keep the arpu_df !

- sample_by_arpu_ranges.count()
- arpu_df = spark.read.parquet(path) // you have to read again !
- sample_by_arpu_ranges=arpu_df.filter(...)
- count

-> With persist with multiple actions :

```
arpu_df = spark.read.parquet(path).persist
sample_by_arpu_ranges=arpu_df.filter(...)
arpu_df.count()
sample_by_arpu_ranges.count()
```

what's happening :

- arpu_df.count()
- arpu_df = spark.read.parquet(path)
- persist  ---> save arpu_df in cache
- count
- sample_by_arpu_ranges.count()
- sample_by_arpu_ranges=arpu_df(take it from cache, don't need to read
  it).filter(...)
- count

Comment: I probably didn't make it clear enough  - I wonder whether the `arpu_df` part will be recomputed to apply each of the filters, or the logical plan builder will understand that it can reuse it in the different parts of the plan?

Comment: it's the same, arpu_df is computed only when you will do an action on it. In fact, the only action is sample_by_arpu_ranges.count(), this action process arpu_df, so arpu_df=get_arpu_df(..) will be really executed at that time